# CSS URL results in a download when loaded directly in Chrome instead of displaying in the browser

Tags: css

- The occurence seems to happen at completely random intervals
- Accompanied by message in Chrome console: **Resource interpreted as
  Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:
  "<url>"**
- It only happens when loaded from disk cache - if a cache refresh is
  forced then it displays in the Chrome as expected
- Currently the CSS file is hosted on sirv.com - this may or may not be
  significant

Here is the HTML code used to load the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<url>" media="all">
```

Comment: You should probably try to reduce the problem - store the css locally to make some tests and see if it helps. I think it's related to your host.

Comment: So when reading cache, it is providing wrong headers and Chrome can't decide if he can open that kind of file or not. Fix cache not providing proper headers for files

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Thanks but I have never managed to replicate the issue myself - I was able to make a video call to someone who could replicate yesterday, but it is virtually impossible to replicate on demand

Answer (score 1):

Remove `media="all"` and it will be solved `<link>` is itself used for loading.
The media attribute specifies what media/device the target resource is optimized for.
The default is always `media="all"` so you don't  need to specify it again